# Relevancy boosting for fields without matching them as part of the search query in elastic search

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

We have a requirement to perform address search against the cached australian address data in Elastic Search ,while performing it we want to boost the rank of documents based on whether
few of the fields appear in the document or not ,the fields should never be considered for matching as part of the search query and must be considered only for ranking purposes ,if they appear the relevancy of documents needs to be boosted based on those parameters,if they do not appear the search result and result should not get impacted in any manner
is there an approach to get his done ,Please advise ? .For reference this capability is already present in FAST ESP Search Engine as XRANK built in method

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch this is achieved by the [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query. You main query goes into `query` and you boosting queries go into `functions`.